# Precision control of double integral with $i\epsilon$ prescription

Tags: numerical-integration

I have the following double integral:
\begin{equation}
F[\epsilon,\Omega,\sigma] = \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{e^{-t^2/2\sigma^2}e^{-T^2/2\sigma^2}}{(t-T-i\epsilon)^2}e^{-i\Omega(t-T)}\,dt\,dT\,.
\end{equation}
Now, there are tricks to solve this *analytically* (in terms of error functions and stuff). However, when I tried to numerically integrate this using NIntegrate, it gives very bad results especially as $\epsilon\to 0$. This is true regardless of the method I tried (GlobalAdaptive, LocalAdaptive, DoubleExponential) with various control over MaxRecursion/MinRecursion and PrecisionGoals or AccuracyGoals. I have also tried to confine my analysis to the strong support of the envelope function $\sim [-5\sigma,5\sigma]\times [-5\sigma,5\sigma]$ and indeed the problem mainly originated from this region.

I do observe, however, that MinRecursion tends to improve results but this has very costly computational time. For example, for the simple choice $\Omega=\sigma=1$ and for $\epsilon\sim 10^{-3}$ reasonable result can be obtained for MinRecursion$\,=5$ but behaves badly for $\epsilon=10^{-4}$. On the other hand, once I increase MinRecursion to $10$, it seems to work for $\epsilon=10^{-4}$ but I cannot do any better. I have also ensured to use only input parameters in integers, so that they use infinite precision instead.

I find it hard to believe that an innocuous looking integral with exact analytic solution can be so ill-behaved under double numerical integration. My questions are:

(1) **Is there a natural setting for which this sort of numerical integral can be dealt with consistently?** I suppose the problem is due to the pole on the real line (before $i\epsilon$ prescription), but being non-expert in numerical analysis, I would like a transparent picture of what happens to this blow-up.

(2) **What is the origin of the blow-up?** Naively the coincident limit $t=T$ should cause problems, but I would have thought that the pole prescription makes the coincident limit disappear. There must be something about complex analysis I am not exactly getting, but this looks quite harmless as it is written.

**EDIT:** I have tried the "Partition" option under LocalAdaptive and it seems to provide some improvements but not very much. I would like to get a coherent larger picture of the integral, however, so the questions still stand from numerical analysis, complex analysis and other perspectives. The following is my latest code (where I kept various entries variable to allow testing various controls), and here $a\equiv \epsilon$, $s\equiv \sigma$ and $gap \equiv \Omega$:

```
NIntegrate[
  Exp[-t^2/(2 s^2)] Exp[-T^2/(2 s^2)] Exp[-I*gap*(t - T)]/(-I a + t-T)^2, 
  {t, tmin, tmax}, {T, tmin, tmax}, 
  MinRecursion -> minR, 
  MaxRecursion -> maxR, PrecisionGoal -> prec, AccuracyGoal -> acc, 
  Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "Partitioning" -> {par1, par2}}]
```

**Update**: I have tried one recent setting involving PrincipalValue, which essentially tries to do principal value integral at t = T. This improves the result quite a bit even with GlobalAdaptive scheme with minimal settings (i.e. Automatic for most other things), but still not working for small enough $\epsilon$. Also, I wonder if PrincipalValue can be used effectively when the singular ``line" is not so clear as in this scenario.

Comment: For reference, please include the `NIntegrate[]` code you were using to evaluate your integral.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The integrand has a near-singularity along the line `T == t`.  This can be specified by the iterator `{T, -Infinity, t, Infinity}` (see second example).  However, `NIntegrate` works more efficiently when the singularity is parallel to a coordinate axis (see first example).  In the first example, we rotate the coordinates so that the near-singularity is along `x = 0`.  In the second example, we help `NIntegrate` by dividing the `T` domain further near `T == t`.

```
Block[{a = 10^-5, gap = 1, s = 1},
  NIntegrate[
   integrand /. {t -> (x + y)/Sqrt[2], T -> (y - x)/Sqrt[2]} // Simplify,
   {x, -Infinity, 0, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {6.4958, -0.279832 + 2.19131*10^-11 I}  *)

Block[{a = 10^-5, gap = 1, s = 1},
  NIntegrate[
   integrand, {t, -Infinity, 0, Infinity},
   {T, -Infinity, t - 2 a, t, t + 2 a, Infinity}]
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {12.8288, -0.279832 + 4.12048*10^-10 I}  *)
```

Even better in this case is the fact that the variables in the integrand can be separated and the double integral factored into two single integrals:

```
inty = E^(-(y^2/(2 s^2)))
intx = integrand/inty /. {t -> (x + y)/Sqrt[2], T -> (y - x)/Sqrt[2]} // Simplify
(*
  E^(-(y^2/(2 s^2)))
  E^(-I Sqrt[2] gap x - x^2/(2 s^2))/(-I a + Sqrt[2] x)^2
*)

Block[{a = 10^-5, gap = 1, s = 1},
  NIntegrate[intx, {x, -Infinity, 0, Infinity}] *
   NIntegrate[inty, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.039515, -0.279833 + 0. I}  *)

Block[{a = 10^-6, gap = 1, s = 1},
  NIntegrate[intx, {x, -Infinity, 0, Infinity}] *
   NIntegrate[inty, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.038009, -0.279824 + 0. I}  *)
```

It is unlikely that the single integrals will be hard to manage.  (The `y` integral can be done exactly.)

Comment: does that mean that if I have a more complicated denominator where I do not have the freedom to rotate it as cleanly as you did, there is no other way out? Or perhaps is there a way to deal with this via contour integral without the $i\epsilon$?

Comment: @Everiana  It's hard to say in general. I think one can always make up an example that will defeat a particular numerical approach. OTOH, one may be able to discover a successful approach by further analysis of the integrand at hand. I think I've only seen contour integration applied to single-variable integrals, so I'm not sure how to answer your last question.

Comment: Actually I found out that for this particular case, we can actually do contour integral! I will update my answer at some point. The idea is to do contour integral of $t$ with poles $T$, and then basically integrate over $T$.